# Excluding Path from Hierarchy based on where clause from Graph DB(Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have tree structure and parent child relation ship like

```
A(ROOT) -> CHILD 1 -> CHILD 2-> CHILD3(LEAF) ==== 1st Path
A(ROOT) -> CHILD 4 --> CHILD 5 -> CHILD6 (LEAF) == 2nd Path
A(ROOT) -> CHILD 7 --> CHILD 8 -> CHILD 9 (LEAF) == 3rd Path
A(ROOT) -> CHILD 10 --> CHILD 11 -> CHILD 12 (LEAF) == 4th Path
```

and so on...

Now I want to write a cypher query to get all the hierarchies for A for 1nd & 3rd Path based on **some condition** and **EXCLUDE** complete path 2nd & 4th from result. What should be the query. **Condition** could be any properties of node like exclude hierarchy of node which have set popular flag as false.

So In this case let say every child has flag **POPULAR**. And if any node has flag set popular to false, we want to exclude that particular child & nodes below it also.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You may find the [Cypher refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) helpful in finding a solution, if you don't have this bookmarked already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Given a path, you can use the `nodes` function to get a list of the nodes in the path.
- List predicates allow you to specify rules about the properties of items in a list.  `none` is the list predicate that specifies that exactly 0 items in the list satisfy the predicate condition.

So, if `your_path` is the variable that represents the path, you're going to be looking at a `where` clause with something like  `none(v in nodes(your_path) where v.popular = false)`

Comment: Can you please give me the cypher. I was trying some cypher but could not write single cypher which could work the way you suggested. Also I have written one cypher 

match p = (n:demo{id:1})-[:CHILD]->(m) WHERE m.is_popular=true
WITH m,p
MATCH p1 = (m)-[CHILD*]->(:demo)
return p1,p

This works only when when the is_popular prop is at direct child of node but in my scenario it could be any any level

Comment: @smartcaveman Looks like the restriction is on node properties, not relationship properties, should be an easy tweak to get your answer to work.

Comment: yeah, restriction is on the node properties.

Comment: @smartcaveman  : I guess this is you are suggesting 
match p = (n:demo{id:1})-[k:CHILD*]->(m)
WIth k,m
where none(rel in k where m.is_popular=false)
return m

But this is not giving me proper result. It is just excluding that particular relationship but not complete path.

Comment: @AnkitBansal - not quite, it's more like `where none(v in nodes(p) where v.is_popular = false)`